# How to get Array values from webmethod to jquery for display?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I want to display the data from database on some time interval so I used Timer control, but on every tick fire the div (chat box) minimizing, so I want to avoid this minimizing on every post back I used Jquery to webmethode concept like below.

to call C# array type webmethod.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {           
            $("#tblCustomers tbody tr").remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetDataByJquery.aspx/GetMessages",
                data: '{roomId: "' + $("[id$=lblRoomId]").html() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        var rows = "<tr>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Username + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Sex + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Text + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.TimeStamp + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.UserID + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>";
                        $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
                    }))
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

Got data from sqlserver and reterning in array.

```
    public static Messages[] GetMessages(string roomId)
    {
        List<Messages> messages = new List<Messages>();           
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinqChatConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                string query = "[Get_Messages]";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId", roomId);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Messages message = new Messages();
                    message.Username = reader.GetString(0);
                    message.Sex = reader.GetString(1);
                    message.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                    message.TimeStamp = reader.GetDateTime(3);
                    message.UserID = reader.GetInt32(4);
                    messages.Add(message);
                }
            }
        }
        return messages.ToArray();
    }
```

but I can't display the data..so how to display it?

Comment: You need to use NewtonSoft.json. There is a method to serialize an object to JSON format.

Comment: Can you give any example please on my condition?.

Comment: Watch the below answer by @Pavan, it looks exact solution to your problem.

Comment: throwing an compile time error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ChatApp.Messages[]' .. at 'return result'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not about WebMethod, it is when data returns to client i.e. in $.ajax, success callback, you are not correctly using `$.map` function and you are also using undefined method `response` (this method is not exist in your code), which leads to JS error and data is not displayed.

So change the code

```
success: function (data) {
   response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
      var rows = "<tr>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Username + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Sex + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Text + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.TimeStamp + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.UserID + "</td>"
      + "</tr>";
      $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
     }))
  }
```

To

```
success: function (data) {
   var rows = $.map(data.d, function (item) {
      return "<tr>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Username + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Sex + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Text + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.TimeStamp + "</td>"
      + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.UserID + "</td>"
      + "</tr>";
    });
    $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
 }
```

Explanation of this code:

`$.map` function is used to transform collection into another collection.
So we are working on `data.d` and for every iteration, we transform object to  html which contains a row and return that html tr row in $.map function body,and we are storing this all returned tr html in a local variable “var rows=…”.

So when `$.map` will exit, we will have all transformed tr html in variable rows, and we can append it in the table’s tbody, which results in data displayed in table format.

Comment: This code also not displaying any row/column in a table.

Comment: @ArmaanAhmed, Are you able to get data on your success callback handler or not? try to log it on console, like `console.log(data.d)` on chrome. If you are getting that, its mean WebMethod is working fine, if not getting that then something wrong with WebMethod.

Answer (score 2):

Use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize an Object to JSON.

Set the response content-type to application/json and serialize the result object and return it.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages);
    return result;
```

**To install Newtonsoft.Json**

Right click on your references folder in your solution explorer and select "Manage Nuget Packages", a wizard will be there.

Write Newtonsoft in search box, it will show Json.Net on top.

Click Install, it will take a few seconds to install.

Comment: is the 'Newtonsoft.Json' library file?

Comment: I added 'Newtonsoft.Json' dll in reference so which namespace I have to use ?

Comment: `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: throwing an compile time error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ChatApp.Messages[]' .. at 'return result'.

Comment: change the return type of your function :)

Comment: to which type of methode?

Comment: `public static string GetMessages(string roomId)`

Comment: Ya I can run the page without any error but cant display the data on page.

Comment: Sir have you any answer?

Comment: for simple serialization you don't need to newtonsoft, you can just `return Json(result)` from your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the JsonResult as below code in order to return serialize object.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public JsonResult testmethod()
    {
        List<YourObject> objectlist = new List<YourObject>();
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = objectlist;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I cant Use 'JsonResult', where it is?